# KVM: High host CPU load after upgrading VM to windows 10 1803

Tags: virtualization, windows-10, cpu, kvm-virtualization

I'm running an Ubuntu 16.04 server with KVM/libvirt/qemu and Windows 10 virtual machine. After upgrading Windows 10 to the latest 1803 version (April 2018 Update), i noticed a slowdown in the VM responsiveness and a too high CPU load in the host.
The tests I did:

- "top" used on the host reports that the qemu-system-x86 process is taking 38-44% of CPU, while the VM is idle and reporting 4-6% of load inside windows process manager. When windows shows 50% of CPU load, the host shows 150-200% cpu load for the qemu-system-x86 process. This 8-10x increase in host CPU load does not occur with the old windows 10 1709 VM.
- "dstat" on the host reports a lot of system->csw, about 13k.
- I tested another system with the same setup with an AMD FX-4300, Ubuntu 17.10 dekstop + kvm, upgraded windows 10 to 1803 and I have the same problem of high host CPU and dstat-csw also on this machine.
- I took a third machine with an intel core i7, installed a new Ubuntu 18.04 desktop + kvm, installed a fresh new Windows 10, installed Virtio drivers available from [here](https://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/direct-downloads/stable-virtio/virtio-win.iso) and I have the same high cpu problem.

What can I do? Am I using the right virtio drivers?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you interpret this properly? If you have 8 Cores, and assign 8 cores to your vm, 25% load on windows will be a load of 2.0 on your host, which might show as 200%, because it's using 2 "CPU" by 100% each.

Comment: I have 4 cores on the host with Ubuntu 17.10, 2coresx2threads=4 on the host with Ubuntu 16.04. VM are configured all with 2 cores.
I expect to find load of qemu-system-x86 on the host a bit higher than 2*windowsVMLoad.
And this is still true on the backup I have of the vm with windows 10 1709: 3%windows cpu load gives 9% of qemu-system-x86 load on the ubuntu host.
When I power off the old 1709VM and power on the new 1803 one, I wait it to be idle, and then windows has 6-7% load (never reached 3%), at the same time qemu-system-x86 on the host ranges from 44% to 54%.

Comment: Also reported here by another user: https://lime-technology.com/forums/topic/71479-windows-10-vm-cpu-usage/

Answer (score 9):

Found someone with the same issue and a possible fix for it here:
https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/high-cpu-load-for-windows-10-guests-when-idle.44531/

Tested changing my own config, and setting hpet to yes in the vm xml fixed it for me.

```
  <clock offset='localtime'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='yes'/>
    <timer name='hypervclock' present='yes'/>
  </clock>
```

hpet part is important.

Comment: It works! Host CPU load is reduced a lot. I have also found another post on reddit which suggested to remove the following parameters from qemu commandline:
    `-no-hpet`
    `-rtc base=localtime,driftfix=slew`
    `-global kvm-pit.lost_tick_policy=discard`
which translates into a slightly different .xml for libvirtd:
    `<timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='delay'/>`
    `<timer name='pit' tickpolicy='catchup'/>`
   `<timer name='hpet' present='yes'/>`
Also with the above rtc/pit settings host cpu usage is reduced.
VM general performances seems to be a bit lower than windows 1709.

Comment: It also seems that <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='discard'/> (instead of 'delay') improves general VM performances. Ubuntu 16.04 does not support it. I upgraded to 18.04.

Comment: for me enabling <synic state='on'> and <stimer state='on'> lowered the cpu usage to under 3%, with almost all cycles used by kernel kvm threads (looking at threads with top, qemu-kvm-ev uses zero cpu on rhel7.5 and kernel 4.16 from fedora28 for a q35 uefi win10 vm); 
source https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1775702

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue with Windows 10 21H1 and `qemu-kvm-4.2.0`.
When windows machine was idle, I got around 30% cpu usage.
After the fix, I get about 5%.

Got the issue resolved by adding `hv_synic` & `hv_stimer` hyperv enlightments.
You might get stuck with the following error

```
error: Failed to start domain mymachine.local
error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: Hyper-V synthetic timers (hv-stimer) requires Hyper-V clocksources (hv-time)
Hyper-V synthetic interrupt controller (hv-synic) requires Hyper-V VP_INDEX MSR (hv-vpindex)
2021-09-22T20:30:06.440656Z qemu-kvm: kvm_init_vcpu failed: Function not implemented
```

In order to get the above enlightments to work, you have to add `hv_time` (which is translated to `hypervclock` in libvirt) and `hv_vpindex` enlightments too.

My final libvirt XML file looks like

```
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <hyperv>
      <relaxed state='on'/>
      <vapic state='on'/>
      <spinlocks state='on' retries='8191'/>
      <vpindex state='on'/>
      <synic state='on'/>
      <stimer state='on'/>
    </hyperv>
    <smm state='on'/>
  </features>

  <clock offset='localtime'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='discard'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='yes'/>
    <timer name='hypervclock' present='yes'/>
  </clock>
```

Disclaimer: This has been done under CentOS 8, but should work under any libvirt controlled KVM.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the current answers worked for me. A workaround that has worked for me is to just keep the Windows 10 task manager open. I'd always noticed that when there would be high CPU usage I'd open the Windows 10 task manager, there would be "System Interrupts" using 100% CPU, but immediately it would go away. Obviously doesn't work for people who aren't keeping an interactive session open, but FWIW.